# Finding the Green function of an operator in QFT

Tags: operators, greens-functions

I'm working on some quantum field theory and have to operate on a field with the following operator:

$$
(x^\mu \partial_\mu + 1)^{-1}
$$

I've been trying to find an explicit form of this operator, but it has proved a challenge. Calling it $\phi$, I know it has to obey:

$$
\int d^4x\> (x^\mu \partial_\mu + 1)\phi = 1
$$

but all my attempts have gotten me nowhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Explicit form how? Would you be happy to know how it works on a convenient basis or you need like an integral expression?

Comment: @MannyC anything to evaluate it! (So really the former)

Comment: A way is writing down the  inverse operator as a series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (x^\mu \partial_\mu)^k$. It works on real analytic functions a least...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not presume pointing you in the right direction, but you might consider the evident Lorentz-invariant eigenfunctions of your operator, namely  the powers $r^n$,
for $r\equiv \sqrt{x^\mu x_\mu}$, 
$$
\frac{1}{1+x^\mu\partial_\mu}  ~ r^n = \frac{1}{1+n}     r^n ~.
$$
It is also easy to quantify the directional eigenfunctions $(a\cdot x)^n$ as well, since the kernel $x^\mu\partial_\mu$ is just a power counter,
$$
x^\mu\partial_\mu  r^n= x^\mu (2 x_\mu)  \frac{n}{2} (r^2)^{n/2-1} =n ~r^n.
$$

Comment: Hi Cosmas, how is this fact derived/obvious to you?  Am I missing something basic?

Comment: OK, expanding the point.

Comment: Ahh okay I was over thinking the act of inverting the operator. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Building on Cosmas' answer. You can extend his definition to a basis of functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$. This is the reason behind my comment before. Any function can be written as a radial function times a [spherical harmonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics#Higher_dimensions)
$$
\varphi(x) = f(|x|) \,Y_{l_1,\ldots l_{d-1}}(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{d-1})\,.
$$
The spherical harmonics can be equivalently represented as polynomials of degree $l_{d-1}$ (where $l_{d-1}\geq l_{d-2}\geq\cdots \geq |l_1|$)
$$
Y_{l_1,\ldots l_{d-1}}(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{d-1}) = \frac{1}{|x|^{l_{d-1}}}C(l_1,\ldots,l_{d-1})^{\mu_1\ldots \mu_{l_{d-1}}} x^{\mu_1}\cdots x^{\mu_{l_{d-1}}}\,,
$$
where the coefficients are symmetric traceless tensors. Clearly in this representation
$$
x^\mu \partial_\mu Y_{l_1,\ldots l_{d-1}}(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_{d-1}) = 0
$$
because the function is homogeneous of degree zero. So now your operator acts only on $f$ and we have reduced the problem to one dimension.

For any sufficiently regular function ($L^2(\mathbb{R})$ should be enough) one can define the [Mellin (inverse) transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform) as
$$
f(x) = (\mathcal{M}^{-1}g)(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \mathrm{d}s\,x^{-s}\,g(x)\,.
$$
Check the link for the conditions on $c$ and the direct Mellin transform used to find $g(x)$. Now for any sufficiently well behaved function $F$ one can define
$$
F\big(-x_\mu\partial^\mu\big)f(|x|) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i \infty}\mathrm{d}s \,F(s)\,|x|^{-s}g(|x|)\,.
$$
Your question regards the special case
$$
F(s) = \frac{1}{1-s}\,.
$$

To summarize, you can decompose any field into a radial and an angular part, do the inverse Mellin transform on the radial part, apply the operator in Mellin space and transform back.

Comment: I do not think it works as it stands: you are using the Euclidean metric, whereas the post refers to the Minkowskian one so that what you indicate as the norm of $x$ has actually a sign.

Comment: This does not matter for the second part of my answer obviously because $f$ is still a one dimensional function. It becomes a bit messier to define the spherical harmonics but it can be done. They will have a continuous label and one of the angles (being the rapidity) will be unbounded.

Comment: I'm a little wary of the signs, can you elaborate on why theres a minus sign in the argument of the capital F, second last equation. Why does F(-O) correspond to O in the integral?

Comment: It's just because the Mellin transform is defined with $x^{-s}$. So $-\partial_\mu x^\mu$ becomes multiplication by $s$.